# Converting lat/lng polygon to bounding boxes

Tags: javascript, node.js, polygon, bounding

I've been trying to find a JavaScript library that can accept an array of lat/lng points (that make up a polygon) and return a new boundary made up from multiple bounding boxes.

The result would be a simplified shape based on the original polygon but containing a much smaller array of points.

The image shows an example for Greater Manchester with the original polygon plotted in orange.  The new boundary would be the outer most dashed line created by the bounding boxes.

I did check for similar questions here but couldn't find the answer.  It would be interesting to hear if anyone else has solved this problem in any programming language.

[image: Bounding boxes overlaying a polygon]